# Random SELECT query based on a key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to randomize a SELECT  based on a key?

I used this query to random my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Is there a function or a way like this to random query based on a **key**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY NEWID(15);

5,1,3,2,4
```

With **same** key:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY NEWID(15);

5,1,3,2,4
```

With **another** key:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY NEWID(36);

2,5,1,3,4
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko : That dosen't work because rand will return the same for the rows

Comment: @DmitryBychenko No, a key (for example 15) define the pattern of randomization.

Comment: Just NEWID(), without any seed?

Comment: @jarlh If we use for example 15, the select query is same ordering every time we use same key .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`HASHBYTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174415.aspx), although it may not perform brilliantly on a large number of rows (although neither does `NEWID()`), e.g.

```
-- CREATE SAMPLE DATA
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tbl_news', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_news;
CREATE TABLE #tbl_news (NewsID INT IDENTITY);
INSERT #tbl_news DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT #tbl_news DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT #tbl_news DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT #tbl_news DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT #tbl_news DEFAULT VALUES;

-- DEFINE YOUR SORT KEY
DECLARE @Key INT = 15;

SELECT  *
FROM    #tbl_news
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NewsID + @Key));

-- SAME ORDER AS FIRST SELECT TO SHOW SORT IS REPEATABLE
SELECT  *
FROM    #tbl_news
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NewsID + @Key));


SET @Key = 36;

-- WITH A NEW KEY SHOW DIFFERENT ORDER
SELECT  *
FROM    #tbl_news
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NewsID + @Key));

-- BUT NEW ORDER IS STILL REPEATABLE
SELECT  *
FROM    #tbl_news
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NewsID + @Key));
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but is there any way for  large number of rows?

Comment: I may have actually spoken to soon, the performance is not that much worse than `NEWID()`, I have just run a comparison on a table of just over 750k rows, and the sort using hash bytes takes 15s to complete, and the sort using `NEWID()` takes 14s (average from 5 runs each)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called random seed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx). Seed make random numbers repeatable. I think solution is to use seed and put them into a table then join this table with your table to find your desired list. See an example below.

```
DECLARE @SEED INT = 100;
DECLARE @SIZE INT = 5;
-- url http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/811913/Generating-a-set-of-random-numbers-in-SQL-Server
WITH RandomNumbers (RowNumber, RandomNumber) AS (
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT  1                         AS RowNumber, 
            RAND(@SEED) AS RandomNumber
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT  rn.RowNumber + 1          AS RowNumber, 
            RAND( 1000000000* RAND(@SEED + rn.RowNumber))  AS RandomNumber
    FROM RandomNumbers rn
    WHERE rn.RowNumber < @SIZE
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT  rn.RowNumber, rn.RandomNumber
FROM RandomNumbers rn
INNER JOIN tbl_news n
ON rn.RowNumber = n.ID
ORDER BY rn.RandomNumber
```